# Why is the text in my title tag showing up as plain text on the page?

Tags: html, title

This was asked before, but it wasn't clear what the solution was, so I'm asking now. I have written an HTML5 page that is not only showing the  element in the bar (as, of course, it should) but also in the first line of the web page. WTH? I have never encountered this problem before and it's completely baffling. What have I done wrong? Any help would be appreciated. My code is below and I've stripped it down to the bare minimum so as to pinpoint the issue.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>MBSeacott.com</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullscreenimg.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, 
MB

Comment: fiddle or it didn't happen ;^)

Comment: Have you tried adding something to the body? Could be a browser thing...

Comment: Can you tell me what is your expected result ? I see nothing wrong with this code. If I save this as HTML and open in a browser, I get a blank page with the title MBSeacott.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have set `display:block` for the `title` element? E.g., with `* {display:block;}` (resp. something other than `none`).

If so, then you could overwrite it, e.g., with `title {display:none;}`. Or, to make sure that no other childs of the `head` element may appear in the future: `head {display:none;}`.

Comment: I finally took a step back  to refocus and it turned out to be something ridiculous (it usually is!). Anyway, I had actually used `*{display:block;}`, and included it with the other resets (`padding:0; margin:0;`). So I listed all the elements used within the page with `display:block;` like so: `head, body, section, article, footer {display:block;}` and it fixed my problem. Thanks so much for your input! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
body * {}
```

instead of

```
* {}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  use:

```css
head {
   display: none;
}
```

to hide everything in the head of the html file